# How to use Org KEYWORD values within exported body?

Tags: org-export, html

How can I get the author's name, the date, or other `#+KEYWORD: value` variables to appear within the exported body?

This is my org-mode file:

```
#+TITLE: Some Title
#+AUTHOR: Foo Bar
#+DATE: 2021-08-21

* some headline
  This does not work:
  - author's name: %a
  - date: %d
```

Note: I'm exporting to HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Org mode defines macros for these things. Try:

```
#+TITLE: Some Title
#+AUTHOR: Foo Bar
#+DATE: 2021-08-21

* some headline
  This works:
  - author's name: {{{author}}}
  - date: {{{date}}}
```

See the "Macro Replacement" section of the manual with `C-h i g(org)macro replacement` for more info.

EDIT: as the OP points out in the comment, the section I pointed to above describes the general mechanism, as well as the specific cases (`author` and `date`) in the text above.

For *any* keyword `FOO`, the value of that keyword can be inserted into the exported output by using the macro call `{{{keyword(FOO)}}}`. The `author` macro e.g. is just a shortcut for the `keyword(AUTHOR)` macro.

Comment: Perfect! While reading this section of the manual I rediscovered `{{{keyword(MY_CUSTOM)}}}`, which is what I really wanted deep down, but didn't know how to ask.